# Eliminate empty values in python dict made of lists and arrays

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary

I want to eliminate all empty value from a dict whose values are a mix of lists and nd array. So I tried with:

```
    res = [ele for ele in ({key: val for key, val in sub.items() if val} for sub in test_list) if ele]
```

but I get the error

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all(). And if I try:
```

---

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'any'
```

I get the error

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'any'
```

So I am wondering if there is a more general way to delete empty values in python `dict`.

Comment: Please fix the post to show the code that uses `any`; you copy-pasted the error message a second time instead.

Comment: But more importantly: where you wrote `{key: val for key, val in sub.items() if val}`, *what is the actual rule* that you have in mind with `if val`? With plain lists, an empty list will fail this and every other possible list will pass; is that what you intend? With the Numpy arrays, which should pass and which should fail?

Comment: You're calling `array.any()` when you should be doing `any(array)`, which is why you're getting the second error. `any` is a built in function and not an attribute of a generic python array. (Fixing this is probably not going to fix your function but it is the cause of the error)

Answer (score 1):

A common way to check empty for empty lists is to check `len(list)`. So assuming your `dict()` looks like so

```
myDict = {
  1: [1,2,3],
  2: [],
  3: np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
}
```

Your list comprehension might look like

```
res = {k:v for k,v in myDict.items() if len(v)}
```

Note the `len(v)` in the dict comprehension

Answer (score 1):

I think you've made this one more step complicated than necessary (as well as not including a complete example!)

The following example creates a new dict `res` with all values of `test_dict` that have non-empty values. I used `len()` here because that works on both lists and nd-arrays. For just lists, I'd omit the call to `len()` and just use `val`.

```
test_dict = {1: [], 2: [1,2,3], 3: [4,5,6]}
res = {key: val for key, val in test_list.items() if len(val)}
```

If you are wanting to use any(), you'd be finding dict values that are lists that contain at least one truthy item:

```
test_dict = {1: [], 2: [1,2,3], 3: [4,5,6]}
res = {key: val for key, val in test_list.items() if any(val)}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Jacob's answer works fine, though it is really inefficient.

Instead, you can take advantage of the built-in `filter()` method to filter out the empty dictionaries, and use the `dict()` method instead of using a `dict` comprehension:

```
res = filter(None, (dict(i for i in sub.items() if len(i[1])) for sub in test_list))
```